# How to quantize float [-a;+a] range to byte

Tags: c#, signal-processing

I have an array of generated samples of noise and i need to convert them to PCM format 8,16,32bit. I know how to do it when range is `[0;max]` but have problem when lower limit is negative.

This is how I do it for the range `[0,max]`:

```
byte quantize(double sample, double max_value)
{
    return (byte)((sample / max_value) * 255.0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show how you do it for `[0,max]` and how it is different for `[-a,a]`

Comment: <code>byte quantize(double sample, double max_value)
{
    return (byte)((sample / max_value) * 255.0);
}</code>

Comment: Add that to the question.

Comment: Can you not just add `a` to the `sample` and `max_value`?

Comment: @Snakerek The answer you accepted is wrong. It does **not** divide the continuous range into 256 equally sized chunks. It divides the continuous range into 255 equally sized chunks, with the only way to get a value of 255 being to give exactly the max as input. There's a reason my answer maybe looked more complicated: because it needs to be for this to be done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can do it for the range `[0,max]` but not `[a,b]`, shift the sample and range. (Note, this assumes that the quantization is linear.)

```
// from question.
byte quantize(double sample, double max_value)
{
    return (byte)((sample / max_value) * 255.0);
}


byte quantize( double sample, double min, double max )
{
    return quantize( sample - min, max - min );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let be `x` in `[-a, a]`.
Then `(x+a)/2a` is in `[0,1]`.
So `256(x+a)/2a` is in `[0,256]`.
So `floor(256(x+a)/2a)` is in `{0, 1, 2, ..., 256}`.
If you get `256`, clamp to `255`.

General purpose functions:

```
//Map x in [0,1] to {0, 1, ..., 255}
byte quantize(double x)
{
    x = (int)Math.Floor(256 * x);
    if (x < 0) return 0;
    else if (x > 255) return 255;
    else return (byte)x;
}

//Map x in [min,max] to {0, 1, ..., 255}
byte quantize(double x, double min, double max)
{
    return quantize((x - min) / (max - min));
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. Code wasn't necessary after your explanation but thanks.